# UseState is not rerendering page after onClick event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have problem to re-render page after setting state via useState hook. State value changes, but page isn't re-rendering.

```
export function langauge(props: Props) {
  const [languageChange, setLanguageChange] = React.useState(strings.getLanguage());

return (
        {props.selected !== 'EN' && (
          <MenuItem onClick={() => {
            locale.changeLanguage('en'),
            setLanguageChange('en')
          }}>English - EN</MenuItem>
         {props.selected !== 'FR' && (
          <MenuItem onClick={() => {
            locale.changeLanguage('fr'),
            setLanguageChange('fr')
          }}>French - FR</MenuItem>
        )} );
}
```

I want to re-render page on language change.

Comment: It will re-render the component on language change, what do you mean by the "page"? If you want it to re-render in other places then don't use local state.

Comment: It's not re-rendering on language change

Comment: @Li357, what is wrong with that?

Comment: How should I write it in your opinion?

Comment: @Li357 criticizing the weird use of the comma operator doesn't really help answer the question

Comment: @worc Hence the FYI on the now delete comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page isn't rerendering because you're not actually conditionally rendering stuff based on the state variable `languageChange`. You're conditionally rendering based on `props.selected`.

Change

```
{props.selected !== 'EN' && <Component />
```

to

```
{languageChange !== 'EN' && <Component />
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, for your solution!